# Mudar texto de tag <a> via Jquery

Tags: jquery

possuo uma pop-up que gera o seguinte codigo html:

```
<a data-val-filinkbutton-type="button" href="#" id="AtribuicaoCodigo_lnkPop" onclick="openDialog(event, this, 'AtribuicaoCodigo_pop');">Regra:</a>
```

Preciso mudar o texto da `Regra:` de acordo com o valor de uma dropdown que está na tela de trás, ou seja no parent. Fiz o seguinte código jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnCopiar').on('click', function (e) {
        if (parent.$('#TipoAtribuicao').val() === '1') {
            $('#AtribuicaoCodigo_lnkPop').text('Comissionado: ');
        }
        else {
            $('#AtribuicaoCodigo_lnkPop').text('Regra: ');
        }
        openDialog(event, this, 'popCopiar', null, 800, 750);
    });
});
```

Porém nada acontece, não está alterando o nome, alguem consegue me dizer o motivo?

Comment: @Sam sim.......

Comment: @Sam é uma popup

Comment: @Sam mas ta certo, dessa forma (parent) o valor está vindo corretamente, unica coisa que não está acontecendo é a troca do texto "Regra" da pop up....

Comment: Pelo que entendi você está mudando o texto da tag "a" antes que ela exista, tente fazer isso depois que o modal é aberto, via callback, timer ou alguma outra coisa.